# Updating list from a function

Tags: python-3.x

This is a sample from a card game (project) Im trying to create

```
p1 = []
p2 = []
player_list = [p1,p2]

def hit(self):
    self.append(random.choice(Deck))
    print(self)

for player in player_list:
    print('Player')
    play = input('Hit or Stay >> ')
    if play != 'hit' or play != 'stay': continue
    if play == 'hit':
        hit(player)
    print(player)
    if play == 'stay':
        print(player)
    print (player_list)
```

When you run the code it doesn't update the player from the hit() function.
Can anyone inform me as to why I am receiving this result?

Comment: you have indentation problem on your post

Answer (score 3):

This condition

```
if play != 'hit' or play != 'stay': continue
```

is always true: play with always be either not 'hit' or not 'stay'.

It should be 'and':

```
if play != 'hit' and play != 'stay': continue
```

A more Pythonic expression is:

```
if play not in ('hit', 'stay'):
    continue
```

You should also account for variations such as 'HIT'. I prefer to convert input to uppercase. For example,

```
if play.upper() not in ('HIT', 'STAY'):
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual, break your code into small, single-purpose functions, and things become easier to reason about.

```
def ask():
    result = None
    while result not in ('hit', 'stay'):
        result = raw_input('hit or stay? >> ')
    return result

def process(player, command):
    if command == 'hit':
        hit(player)

for player in players:
    command = ask()
    process(player, command)
    print player
```

Now you can *independently* make sure that each of them work. The bug in `ask` would be much easier to detect than in the whole interleaved logic of the original code.